# Excel conditional formatting after SQL Query

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Hi have an excel spreadsheet which runs an SQL Query against my database and returns a table as per the below pic:

[image: Screenshot of how table currently is]

And I have Conditional formatting setup as per the below pic's:
[image: Conditional Formatting Rule]
[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager]

So the 1's and 0's should actually be ticks and crosses, if i edit each cell where there is a 1 or a 0 and just press return (so not actually change the value) then the conditional formatting gets applied and it looks like is is meant to (pic below)

[image: Screenshot of how table should be]

So my question is why isn't the conditional formatting working after refreshing the sql query, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by re-calculing everything from VBA: include this after your Query refresh:

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False  
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

Without VBA you could try:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to recheck all dependencies and recalculate all formulas.

Comment: At the moment my query isnt being done through VBA, so im guessing my best solution would be to move the query to VBA, so when i run the macro that would execute the query, it would then finish off by running what you suggested?

Comment: Have you tried the second suggestion using *CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F9*? If it doesn't, then yes VBA would be a solution for you.

Comment: Well ive just rebuilt the spreadsheet from scratch and it now works without VBA or pressing the key combination. I must of hit some kind of bug but cant reproduce it now.